Get user information who are added in the channel using invite link in telegram
I have a private channel on telegram in which I have added my bot. I am able to create unique links for each user to join the channel. Now I want to know userID of the user who have joined the channel. The reason for me to get userID is because the channel is subscription based and I would want to remove the user once their subscription ends and they don't resubscribe.
Currently I am using Go for writing the code. I have used https://github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api package. I am able to create an invite link for each user but cannot get userID when they join the group.
I have read few questions on stackoverflow regarding the same. Most of it suggested to use /getUpdates API but I have not found any luck using that so now I am not very sure how to do it. I have seen few packages in python where userID is been fetched but nothing of that kind is found with the package that I am using.

Actually, the solution is to use the /getUpdate method itself. You need to explicitly specify you need updates of chat_member events.
Here's a sample code in Go.
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    tgbotapi "github.com/go-telegram-bot-api/telegram-bot-api/v5"
)

func main() {
    bot, err := tgbotapi.NewBotAPI(os.Getenv("BOT_TOKEN"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    bot.Debug = true

    log.Printf("Authorized on account %s", bot.Self.UserName)

    u := tgbotapi.NewUpdate(0)
    u.Timeout = 60
    u.AllowedUpdates = []string{"message", "chat_member"}

    updates := bot.GetUpdatesChan(u)

    for update := range updates {
        if update.ChatMember == nil {
            continue
        }
        
        // Process the ChatMember info here
        print(update.ChatMember)
    }
}

Now, when a user is joined in the chat your bot will receive an update that kind of look like this:
{
  "chat": {
    "id": -1002232751336,
    "type": "channel",
    "title": "Channel Title",
    "username": null,
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "is_forum": false
  },
  "from": {
    "id": 123456789,
    "is_bot": false,
    "first_name": "User's First Name",
    "username": "some_user_name",
    "language_code": "en"
  },
  "date": 1719777260,
  "old_chat_member": {
    "user": {
      "id": 123456789,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "User's First Name",
      "username": "some_user_name",
      "language_code": "en"
    },
    "status": "left"
  },
  "new_chat_member": {
    "status": "member",
    "user": {
      "id": 123456789,
      "is_bot": false,
      "first_name": "User's First Name",
      "username": "some_user_name",
      "language_code": "en"
    }
  },
  "invite_link": {
    "invite_link": "https://t.me/+actual-invite-link",
    "creator": {
      "id": 9876543210,
      "is_bot": true,
      "first_name": "Your Bot Name",
      "username": "myawesomebot"
    },
    "creates_join_request": false,
    "is_primary": false,
    "is_revoked": false,
    "name": "Optional name for the invite link (if set with createChatInviteLink)"
  }
}

This is basically of type ChatMemberUpdated as specified in the Telegram Bot API documentation.
So obviously you're looking for the update.ChatMember.From.ID as the User ID.
Hope this helps!
